# Ionic 3: Tab icons only visible at click

Tags: ios, angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I'm currently facing a strange problem:
I use Ionic 3 and ionic tabs like this:

```
<ion-tabs>
  <ion-tab [root]="mapPage" tabTitle="Map" tabIcon="map"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="addPage" tabTitle="Hinzufügen" tabIcon="add"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="facebookPage" tabTitle="Facebook" tabIcon="logo-facebook"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="morePage" tabTitle="Mehr" tabIcon="more"></ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

The icons are only visible when the Tab is selected, despite the facebook icon. I want that all icons are visible even if they are not selected. 
It looks like this on my iOS/Android Device. With ionic cordova run browser it looks all good.

[image: Visibility of icons]
[image: Visibility of icons]

Does anybody else had this problem?

Comment: consider tabIcon as only map, add, facebook etc as it auto-select the icon based on the platform

Comment: did it already. but same result

Comment: Hey man, i recall I also had the same issue with iOS only. So you say you tried explit tabIcon="ios-map" and it didn't work as well?

Comment: @SergeyRudenko yes it doesn't work nor with "map" either with "ios-map"

Comment: Yeah i recall the same for ios;/ please file issue with ionic team.

Answer (score 0):

As @Suryan said, ionic will auto select platform, please refer attached image. If it didn't work please go with trail and error method. 
[image: Ionic docs auto-select platform]

Comment: thanks for your answer, but I already tried to use the icons like this. It doesn't work either. I don't know what else I can do.

Comment: Earlier when I'm was working with Ionic, I had same issue with some icons. Can you please ask a question to ionic team via github. I think they will give solution to this.